# Firebase OnSuccessListener is being called when it should fail

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I disconnected my internet connection and tested my app. When I add something to the database, I check if it was successfully added using the default `OnSuccessListener`. However, even when my application is in Airplane mode or there is no internet connection, `OnSuccessListener` is getting called, and `OnFailureListener` isn't.

This is weird, it shouldn't get called.

Code:

```
database.child("blah").child(key).setValue(objects).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull Void T) {
            //Do whatever
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            //display error message
        }
    });
```

But for some reason, `OnSuccessListener` is still being called. This is unbelievably irritating. Even when I add an `OnCompleteListener`instead with `if(task.isSuccess())` it does the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ِAs The Doc Says:

> Firebase apps remain responsive even when offline because the Firebase
>   Realtime Database SDK persists your data to disk. Once connectivity is
>   reestablished, the client device receives any changes it missed,
>   synchronizing it with the current server state.

so your data has successfully added to the **disk** and once you go online it will be synchronized to the **cloud**.

Comment: Nice **explanation**. But is there a way to **prevent it**?

Comment: Because my application gets very buggy when it adds it and there's no internet connectionn

Comment: if you don't want real-time database so why you use Firebase Database ?

Comment: Because I want it Realtime, but I don't want it to work offline since it messes my recyclerview up. I hope you don't want me to give up tens of features just to stop one feature I don't like.

Comment: i think you can check for Connectivity before doing the firebase database work if it's connected keep goind do the work else don't

Comment: I'll try, but is there a way to check for INTERNET connection, not just WI-FI? All I've found on SO is how to check if there's a WIFI connection alone

Comment: yes here it is : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html

Comment: From what I read on Stackoverflow, that only checks if there's a WIFI connection, so if there's no internet but there is WI-FI this will still return that there is internet

Comment: Yes you can make sure to write only if the internet is available quite easily: **Instead on using setValue, user a transaction** : [doc here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#save_data_as_transactions). Transaction only succeed when you are connected to internet.

Comment: @AbAppletic look at [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-presence) at **Detecting Connection State** section, you can listen to `.info/connected` to check if the user is connected to the firebase database server or not.