# How to check whether Firebase cache data is synced or not?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase offline capabilities enabled by the following line:

`database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);`

I have a table which is synced:

`database.child(TABLE_POSTS).keepSynced(true);`

When I put data to the table I need to know whether the data was saved locally only or committed to the remote server as well. This is required to update UI for the user to understand his data is available on other devices. I'm using ComplitionListener now which is triggered only when remote server receive this data, but ComplitionListener is not alive after app restart.

Is any way to verify that child you are accessing in Firebase is synchronized with the remote server when you offline?

Comment: Did you write to Firebase regarding this issue? I want to know the same thing for one of my app.

Comment: No, i have no ticket to Firebase related to this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are offline is obvious that all your data is saved and queried locally because there is no internet connection. So, in order know if your Firebase database is synchronized, first you need to verify if you are online or not. If you are online the `ComplitionListener` is the solution, if you are offline, everything is saved locally.

Comment: I don't need to check the state of the whole database, but i need to check each child separately. So in the scenario you described i have to store each unsynced child separately in my own database or add to them an additional field "synced=false", because if I restart the app and access all table childs by using ValueEventListener i will get all childs - synced and unsynced.

Comment: You can add a new field `"synced=false"` but remember, the value of `synced` in the real time database will always be `true` because if have now internet connection, you cannot write it online, to change the value to `false`. This data will only be saved locally.

Comment: The main problem is that i fill no difference when accessing database in online or offline. Okay, I can check that I'm offline when put something in the table. So in offline ComplitionListener will no be triggered, however the data will be in the table anyway. And when I read the data from that table again(without being online) i can't identify whether the particular child was synced with the remote server or not...

Comment: Let me explain something. If you are using setPersistenceEnabled(true); means that you'll be able to query your the database even if you are offline. This is happening because Firebase creates a local copy of your database. Every change that is made while you are offline, will be updated on Firebase servers once you are back online. To be more clear, every client that is using a Firebase database and uses setPersistenceEnabled(true) maintains it's own internal (local) version of the database. When data is updated, it is first written to this local version of the database.

Comment: `ComplitionListener' is not working when you are offline, it only works when you are online and is called only when the data was written on the server. To identify if particular child was synced, just verify your connection. If  you are offline, it's obvious that everything was synced locally, if you are online, everything is synced on the servers.

Comment: It looks not correct for me, because i want an exact child, not the whole database. Just guess i have a list of posts and when I offline - some posts were loaded from server, some posts can be posted by the user , i.e. local. So some data is synced and some data is not..

Comment: What have explained above, at the same time works for the entire database and at the same time for a single child. You need just to check your connectivity.

Comment: Nope. When i offline i still can't differentiate which items are already saved in remote database and which are only saved locally and not yet synced.

Comment: It's obviuos that when you are offline, all your data is saved locally. That's why i said to check the internet connection.

Comment: No, it is not correct. Not all data, some of the data was already synced and persist on the remote server. 

Of course I can have some buffer on my end and keep unsynced items there, but I'm asking whether firebase can tell me which items are not synced.

Comment: When you write data into a Firebase database you use also [OnSuccessListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/tasks/OnSuccessListener). Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I'm not using tasks, looks like OnSuccessListener is related to Tasks. I follow firebase for Android guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write and use updateChildren() with CompletionListener to write data into the database.

Comment: No, you can use also `addOnSuccessListener`. Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836277/firebase-onsuccesslistener-is-being-called-when-it-should-fail). So you can use setValue().addOnSuccessListener... and see if is synced.

Comment: No difference - it is working same way as ComplitionListener i.e. not alive after app restart. So when you restart app in offline and get items from db you can't identify whether specific item is synced or not.

Comment: Then i recomand you writting to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/)